# Not understanding the path of files in Python exe output

Tags: pyinstaller, exe

my Python project works in editor. I get .exe output from Python (.py) program. The .exe file could not understand the path of the files.

```
import os
a = os.getcwd() + "\\Logs\\" # Find the log directory

# Read the text in the Paths.txt file inside the logs directory
b = open (a + "Paths.txt", "r").read()
```

When the code is executed in the editor, the text inside the file is read and the file path is understood. But when executing the .exe file, the program can not detect the path of the log file.

```
Log file path at runtime (in editor or .py): currect and understood
'C:\\Users\\mohammad\\Desktop\\projects\\Logs\\Paths.txt'
Log file path at runtime (in .exe file): not currect
'C:\\Users\\mohammad\\Desktop\\projects\\dist\\Logs\\Paths.txt'
```

I tried some methods such as short route but it did not work.

Also, due to my problems, I output Python file as follows:

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile --add-binary "C:\\Users\\mohammad\\Desktop\\projects\\pythoncom310.dll\\;." Start.py
```

And i'm using version 3.9 of Python and the VScode editor. Thanks for your time

Comment: When you execute python through the command line, the current working directory of the python interpreter is not the same as when you run it through the editor, for which ever reason. The problem can be avoided by not using `os.getcwd()` to define a path. Instead actually define a path like `a = r'C:\Users...'

Comment: It is true. This method works, but my program is supposed to run on a large number of computers, and it is not clear where each person will place the files. So I used that function to display and understand the location of the files anywhere in the system. what's the solution? What should I do so that my program can understand the path to the log directory in whatever path it is located?

Comment: Related, but not an direct answer to your question (because I don't know - sorry). I would recommend using `os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'Logs')`, especially if you intend to use it on multiple machines as as adding `\\` will fail on a unix machine for example, while `os.path.join` will work.

Comment: This method is similar to my method and does not work. So how does a Python exe file, which works on many systems, understand the path and read the file? I want him to understand their paths dynamically